# Is a Kähler class of the submanifold always deducible from the outer space?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifolds, $Y$ a compact submanifold of $X$, the map $i:Y\to X$ is an inclusion map, then we know $Y$ is a Kähler manifold, and my question is:

> For any Kähler class $\omega_Y$ of $Y$, is there always a Kähler class $\omega$ of $X$, such that the restriction of $\omega$ to the submanifold $Y$ is $\omega_Y$?

or equivalently,

> Let $C_X,C_Y$ be the Kähler cones of $X,Y$ respectively, then for the map $i:Y\to X$, is the pull back $i^*:C_X\to C_Y$ a surjective map?

this question is important because if we add the condition that $H^2(Y,\mathcal O)=0$, then we can alway pick a Kähler class of $X$, such that the restriction to $Y$, denoted as $\omega_Y$, satisfies: $\omega_Y\in H^2(Y,\mathbb Q)$.

I guess it is true, but I find it hard to prove it, can someone help me? or give a counter-example? Any comment is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this? Take $Q=\Bbb P^1\times \Bbb P^1$, the usual quadric in $\Bbb P^3$. The Kähler form on $\Bbb P^3$ restricts to $\pi_1^*\omega + \pi_2^*\omega$, where $\omega$ is the usual Kähler form on $\Bbb P^1$ and $\pi_j$ are the obvious projections. Take instead the Kähler form $2\pi_1^*\omega + \pi_2^*\omega$ on $Q$. It cannot be the restriction of a Kähler form on $\Bbb P^3$ (since every Kähler form is cohomologous to a positive scalar multiple of the usual one).

Comment: Maybe your answer is sensible, but I find it difficult to read, for example, I don't know what the obvious projections $\pi_1,\pi_2$ mean, I guess it means the projection form $Q$ to the first and second factor, and I think $Q$ has an inclusion to $\mathbb P^3$ is not obvious to me, last I don't think every Kähler form shoud be cohomologous to a positive scalar multiple of the usual one, it is only the case for dimension 1, but for dimension greater than 2, the difference is not necessarily $0$ in the cohomology group.

Comment: If you post questions on Kähler geometry, I assume you are sophisticated enough to understand standard language. I am not sure I understand what you mean about dimensions. The second cohomology of $\Bbb P^3$  is $1$-dimensional.

Comment: oh I forget that the second cohomology of $\mathbb P^3$ is 1-dimension, then it is indeed a good counter-example. Acturally after I put this question, I realized that  it is not true, consider a projective $K3$ surface embedded in a complex projective space,for the pull back map of the Kähler cones, the dimension of $H^{1,1}$ may be greater in the image, thus can't be a surjective map. And indeed I am not familiar enough with Kähler geometry, so I need to consider why $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ is embedable in $\mathbb P^3$, but thanks anyway.

Comment: It's the usual quadric $xy-zw=0$. Or you can think of it as the Segre embedding of $\Bbb P^1\times \Bbb P^1$.

Comment: I guess the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem says that it should work for hypersurfaces $V\subset\Bbb P^n$ for $n\ge 4$, as then the restriction map $H^2(\Bbb P^n)\to H^2(V)$ will be an isomorphism.

Comment: Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold, if its universal covering $\tilde{X}$ admits an isometric splitting: $\tilde{X}=\mathbb C^n\times P$, $P$ being a projective manifold, for a Kähler form $\omega$ of $X$, it induces a unique metric $\tilde{\omega}$ for $\tilde{X}$, by restriction to $P$, we get a unique Kähler form of $Y$: $\omega_Y$, the question is: is the induction surjective? or for any Kähler class $\omega_Y$ of $Y$, is there always exist a Kähler class of $X$ which induces exactly the Kähler class $\omega_Y$ for $Y$?